# Random wave / zig zag lines in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, technical-drawing

Is it possible please to achieve the "Desired Effect" (as below), 

**randomly**, using an Illustrator tool, 

WITHOUT having to: 


i) use the **Pen tool**, and ii) the **Zig Zag** effect?

[image: Can it be achieved?]

For your info @joojaa, check this out: https://github.com/uber/ludwig
[image: https://github.com/uber/ludwig]

Comment: You can script it. And you can write a api plugin. Aside form that you can do this by manually drawing with line tool, as that matches your criteria. It would be better to explain why you need this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Wrinkle tool on some straight lines.

Example

[image]

Comment: You are a genius, @Billy Kerr! Thanks man!